# Optimising mysql insert query via python

Tags: python, mysql

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="xxx.xx.xx.x",   
                    user="xxx",       
                    passwd="xxx",  
                    db="xxxx")
for loop on json data:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('Insert Query')
    db.commit() 
db.close()
```

Would it be possible for me to improve this query? I'm considering doing multiple cursor.execute before db.commit()

I'm unsure how db.commit() works and the importance of it.

I'm basically looping a json data and inserting it with a loop. I cannot avoid having multiple inserts.

Comment: `INSERT INTO tab_name(col_list) VALUES (...),(...),(...),(...)`. Insert multiple values at once.

Comment: @lad2025 I cant do that, the Loop is a must. I just have to do multiple Insert, cant help it.

Comment: Is `Insert Query` a string? because you can always create a string the way you want. and send the execute every 10 values or something.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza It's not a string. It has %s in value

Comment: Then maybe you could Improve your question with a more clear sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how `json_data` is structured you should be able to use [`.executemany()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany):

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="xxx.xx.xx.x",   
                     user="xxx",       
                     passwd="xxx",  
                     db="xxxx")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.executemany('Insert Query',json_data)
db.commit()
cursor.close()
db.close()
```

Comment: Can I do data processing in the sql statement value %s eg. str(%s)

Comment: No you cannot do it in that way. There may be another way.